# How to allocate heap memory to a java program

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a java program which create 20 different string objects inside a infinite for loop

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i >=0 ; i++){
    String s = new String("Test");
    String s1 = new String("Test");
    /*creating more string objects here */
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

and ran this program with java -Xms1m -Xmx1m HelloWorld[image] and opened VisualVM to moniter the heap size. I am not sure why does it show 2,097,152 B for both size and max at the top. **Shouldnt it be 1,000,000 ?** And i am also wondering why does use not grow above  700,000 B . **it is always between 300000 and 700000**

please see the attachment and not sure why there is a message under CPU that "Not supported for this JVM"?

Comment: Looks like gc is smart enough to detect that you create new instances for every iteration inside loop so they are gc-eligible on next iteration. if you change your code to create a list before loop, add new strings to list inside loop and then iterate over that list to print values outside of `for` loop you will see that all available memory will be used

Comment: A heap size as small as 1MiB is not supported; 2MiB is the minimum. Besides that, as @Ivan mentioned, your `String` instances are temporary and will get garbage collected. This will happen in a minor collection when the “Eden” space is full, which is a fraction of your heap. Only still referenced objects, called “survivors” may get transferred to the other memory region.

Answer (score 1):

There are several JVM flags which you could use:

- -Xmx set max heap momory for particular JVM (use like this: -Xmx2G. It will limit available heap to 2GBs)
- -Xms sets initial allocated heap amount for JVM (use ike this: -Xms2G. It will set initial heap size to 2GBs)

You could always set garbage collecting algorithm from set of existing algos:

- -XX:+UseG1GC uses G1 gc
- -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC uses Concurrent mark and sweep gc

You could check some of the flags here: http://files.zeroturnaround.com/pdf/zt_JVM-options-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you. How to set heap memory in bytes. I am trying to run a simple java program which creates objects of strings in a loop and it to throw out of memory after max heap size is reached

Comment: @question_tech -Xmx100k  will set max heap to 100 kilobytes

Comment: it did not allow me.I got this error "Error occurred during initialization of VM Too small initial heap"

Comment: @question_tech Set max to 128 MBs. It will take bit more time to reach OOM

Comment: Hi Ivan - i edited my question. This is what i see on VisualVM